# C++: Unexplainable behavior with cout and pointer to char

Tags: c++, output, cout, c-strings, char-pointer

After printing a pointer to an int, I print a pointer to a char:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i;
    cout << "&i: " << &i << endl;

    char q = 'q';
    cout << "&q: " << &q << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I get the following output as expected:

```
&i: 0xffffcc0c
&q: q
```

However, if I comment out `cout << "&i: " << &i << endl;`, and run the program again, I get the following unexplained output:

```
&q: q����
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

If it has to do with `operator<<` inserting into the stream until it finds a null character, then why do I get the expected output when I include `cout << "&i: " << &i << endl;`?

**NOTE**: I am not expecting to get the address of q from cout. I am expecting to get the C string pointed to by &q. What bugs me is how the output just prints the 'q' if I include the line `cout << "&i: " << &i << endl;` beforehand. However, if I comment that line out, there is garbage data in the output. Why is there not garbage data in my output when I include the line `cout << "&i: " << &i << endl;`?

Comment: @iammilind Not a duplicate. I am not expecting an address but a C string. However, I think you answered my question:
"It's worth noting that printing a non NUL terminated c_str is a **undefined behavior**. Which happens in your case. That's why cout sequences also makes a difference in your compiler. It may or may not make such difference in my compiler." Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The bit `&q` thinks it is a string.

Therefore will print up to the null character. hence the extra output

Comment: Then why don't I get extra output when I include the line `cout << "&i: " << &i << endl;` beforehand?

Comment: Because `&i` is an integer pointer - and treated differently

Comment: @Daniel It's worth noting that printing a non NUL terminated `c_str` is a **undefined behavior**. Which happens in your case. That's why `cout` sequences also makes a difference in your compiler. It may or may not make such difference in my compiler.

Comment: @DanielGilbert, If you mean the `&q` output changes depending on the other line being present, it's because printing the string starting at `&q` is going beyond the single character of memory you own, which is undefined behaviour. You can't safely rely on any particular behaviour.

Comment: @iammilind - `std::string` is not involved - C strings (or lack of) are